# How do I align the comboPanels within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I am trying to create a simple GUI using NetBeans. I have multiple comboPanels in my JFrame, but I cannot seem to fit them properly. I have the tried using BorderLayout.NORTH, SOUTH etc. but they end up overriding each other or just discombobulated in general.  Below is the code 
I am using for the comboPanel. I have tried re arranging
and playing around with the positioning but no luck.

```
guiFrame.add(comboPanel,   BorderLayout.NORTH );
guiFrame.add(comboPanel_2, BorderLayout.EAST);
guiFrame.add(comboPanel_3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
guiFrame.add(comboPanel_4, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Comment: The right way to do this is to use a [GUI builder tool.](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)  Trying to code this with raw objects is possible, but not easy.  GUI builders will make much better code and are faster and easier to use.  Win all the way around.

Comment: Why not `GridLayout(2, 2)`?

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.  Note that the suggestion by @trashgod would result in 2 columns and two rows of 'aligned' combo boxes, but I think a single column of 4 would work better for most users.

Comment: Thank you trashgod and @Andrew Thompson, using GridLayout 1,4 works best in this situation.

Comment: Am glad you got it sorted.  I expect @trashgod is as well.  :)  Now you might write up an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GridBagLayout.  Check this link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html